# Makefile design for arbitrary structure

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have my code organized into an arbitrary directory structure. For example, I have a directory containing source files, header files, other directories, each containing other sources and headers and possibly other directories inside, etc.

I want to create a GNU makefile that compiles each of the .c files to .o files, then combines all the .o files in an executable.

If I were to do this with bash, it would be something like:

```
for c in `find . -type f -name \*.c`; do
    gcc -c $c
done

find . -type f -name \*.o | xargs gcc -o main
```

Can I do something similar with GNU make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You can easily define a variable as the result of a shell command; use your find command to define a `SRC` variable, and make your target executable depend on `SRC`; i.e.,

```
SRC =  $(shell find . -type f -name \*.c)

executable: $(SRC:.c=.o)
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Does GNU make not support something like this without the use of the shell?

Comment: There may me something special with wildcards (double asterisks?) but I don't recall off the top of my head. The shell form works fine for me.

Comment: Make wildcards aren't very flexible. This is probably the best you can do.

Comment: You need to use `$^` (which expands to all dependencies) and not `$<`, which expands only to the first one).

Comment: I get the following error when trying that: `/bin/sh: find . -type f -name \*.c: command not found`.

Comment: Sorry, quotes not needed. Just `$(shell find . -type f -name \*.c)`